# Time dependence of mixing temperature of a solid with a liquid

Tags: thermodynamics

let's assume we have the following situation: A person throws a stone with known temperature, mass and known heat capacity in water (known temperature, etc.). How can I calculate the temperature of the water as a function of the time? For the equilibrium state this seems to be very easy but for non-equilibrium proceses, what do I need to assume or which principles do I need? And what is about the porcess of vaporization? How can I take this into account, when the energy of the hot stone is enough to vaporize the whole water?

Thank you vrey much!
Peter

Comment: Not sure if you are aware of the fact that temperature of the water is not evenly distributed in this case. When you calculate temperature, where do you want to estimate this temperature?

Answer (score 0):

As there is a certain lack of answers here ... What you would need to do would be to first calculate the temperature profile which results from the spread of heat from the stone once it is thrown in. A good approximation would be Fickian diffusion to simulate that. Now comes the actually hard part: you need to implement some kind of vaporisation kinetics. As soon as a certain temperature is reached, vaporisation will slowly start and I am positive some people have measured the kinetics of that process. The problem is that I am not sure how you can well handle this vaporisation in your simulation as you will now suddenly have a two phases system surrounding your stone and you need to include effects like the bubbles rising, the bubbles recooling and recondensating (and in general the heat transport and mass transport between vapor and water at the surface) and you need to take into account that further classical heat diffusion will only take part in the liquid phase. I am sure a good finite elements simulation is able to do that, but I do think it is not a trivial problem.
In general you have found the difference between equilibrium and non-equilibrium thermodynamics - the former is a lot easier ;)